# JOIN or Conditional Logic Between 4+ Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Full disclosure, this is a homework question, but I have 20 more of these that are much more difficult, I just really can't wrap my head around some of the more complicated statements, so I'd appreciate the help before I just give up on the assignment completely. The professor and TA declined any help.

I'm using the 'HR' table that is present as a demo in all Oracle DBs. **I need to create a unique listing of all jobs in a particular department along with the locations.** It has the tables: REGIONS, LOCATIONS, DEPARTMENTS, JOBS, and EMPLOYEES of the form described below:

Locations:

```
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 LOCATION_ID                   NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 STREET_ADDRESS                     VARCHAR2(40)
 POSTAL_CODE                        VARCHAR2(12)
 CITY                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 STATE_PROVINCE                     VARCHAR2(25)
 COUNTRY_ID                     CHAR(2)
```

Jobs:

```
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 JOB_ID                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB_TITLE                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(35)
 MIN_SALARY                     NUMBER(6)
 MAX_SALARY                     NUMBER(6)
```

Employees:

```
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 EMPLOYEE_ID                   NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
 FIRST_NAME                     VARCHAR2(20)
 LAST_NAME                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
 EMAIL                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
 PHONE_NUMBER                       VARCHAR2(20)
 HIRE_DATE                 NOT NULL DATE
 JOB_ID                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 SALARY                         NUMBER(8,2)
 COMMISSION_PCT                     NUMBER(2,2)
 MANAGER_ID                     NUMBER(6)
 DEPARTMENT_ID                      NUMBER(4)
```

Departments:

```
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DEPARTMENT_ID                 NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 DEPARTMENT_NAME               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 MANAGER_ID                     NUMBER(6)
 LOCATION_ID                        NUMBER(4)
```

So of course I can think through how the relational algebra kind of goes, but I have no clue how it would go in SQL syntax. I of course know how to do more trivial joins, but I'm not understanding how to agregate all of the requirements into one statement. I want to get all UNIQUE or DISTINCT JOB_IDs where DEPARTMENT_ID=80,Then do a join on Jobs to get the matching JOB_TITLE,then derive LOCATION_ID from DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID and finally join Locations to my original JOB_TITLE selection WHERE LOCATION.LOCATION_ID=DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID. So what does that look like. Do I have to do 3 joins to get all the information in one selection?

Answer (score 0):

Smth like that, perhaps

New-fashioned joins:

```
select tloc.*, tdept.*, tjobs.* 
from locations tloc
  inner join departments tdept on (tloc.location_id=tdept.location_id)
  inner join employees templ on (tdept.department_id=templ.department_id)
  inner join jobs tjobs on (templ.employee_id=tjobs.employee_id)
where 
  tdept.department_id=80
```

Old-fashioned joins:

```
select tloc.*, tdept.*, tjobs.* 
from locations tloc, departments tdept, employees templ, jobs tjobs 
where 
  tloc.location_id=tdept.location_id 
  and tdept.department_id=templ.department_id 
  and templ.employee_id=tjobs.employee_id
  ----
  and tdept.department_id=80
```

Comment: perhaps a reversal of priority? good proper standard explicit joins first?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. Add 'Where' condition as per your requirement.

```
select (select j.job_title from jobs j where j.JOB_ID=x.JOB_ID) as Job_Title ,
        (select dp.department_name from department dp where dp.department_id) as Department_Name,
        (select l.City || l.State_province from Location l where l.location_id = x.location_id) as Location
(select 
        e. JOB_ID,
        D.DEPARTMENT_ID,
        d.location_id
from Employees e inner join Department d on e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
group by l.location_id,d.DEPARTMENT_ID , e.JOB_ID) x
```

Answer (score 0):

This is intended to get you started. The core of your need comes from 2 tables employee (for job_id) and department (for location_id) and the relationship between employee and department is via the shared department_id column (this becomes the join)

```
SELECT
      e.JOB_ID
    , d.LOCATION_ID
FROM Employees e
INNER JOIN Departments d ON e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE e.DEPARTMENT_ID = 80
```

Now you need to figure how to get the "uniqueness"

One way is to add `select distinct` and while this will work, it does limit your options

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      e.JOB_ID
    , d.LOCATION_ID
FROM Employees e
INNER JOIN Departments d ON e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE e.DEPARTMENT_ID = 80
```

OR, to use `GROUP BY` which open up other possibilities such as aggregations

```
SELECT
      e.JOB_ID
    , d.LOCATION_ID
    , COUNT(*) as count_of_employees
FROM Employees e
INNER JOIN Departments d ON e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
WHERE e.DEPARTMENT_ID = 80
GROUP BY
      e.JOB_ID
    , d.LOCATION_ID
```

What I leave for you to discover is how to bring the names into the result.